# service / subscription manager engine

Tags: java, e-commerce, service, subscription

Is there a good opensource service/subscription manager engine that contains things like service dependencies (i.e. if I choose service A, I also need Service B and Service C), subscription types, start and termination etc...

I'm building a site that sells various services and subscriptions and would prefer not to have to write that code as I'm pretty sure it's been done many times over (e.g. in e-commerce sw), but I'd prefer a small library / egine instead of having to integrate with an e-shop.

Answer (score 1):

If your "Service" is just Java classes/package/modules then you can use Spring or any other DI container that supports lifecycle hookups.

If by "Service" you mean something big/bloated/enterprise you can also look into [OSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi).

But for a small/library engine I suggest you look at [plexus](http://plexus.codehaus.org/) and [picocontainer](http://www.picocontainer.org/lifecycle.html).